# Print java array into HTML code

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

Ok. Here is my full code. My problem is that, when trying to use in my javascript/html code the **string array** "comentarios" I don't know how to "pass" the entire array. I've been working for a few months with applets but I never had to pass a array to "html like code". How can I solve this? Thanks

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ValoracionesDos extends HttpServlet implements SingleThreadModel{
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException{
PrintWriter toClient = res.getWriter();
int numRows=3;
String comentarios[] = new String[numRows];
comentarios[0]="hello";
comentarios[1]="me";
comentarios[2]="bye";
int i=0;
    toClient.println("<html>");
    toClient.println("<body>");
    toClient.println("<script Language=JavaScript>");
    toClient.println("var len = " + numRows+";");
    toClient.println("var myrest = new Array();");
    toClient.println("for(i = 0; i < len; i++){");
         toClient.println("myrest[i]='"+ comentarios[i]+"';");
         toClient.println("}");
    toClient.println("var myTable= '<table border=10 cellspacing=3 cellpadding=3>'");
    toClient.println("for(i = 0; i < " + numRows + "; i++){");
       toClient.println("myTable+='<tr>';");
       toClient.println("myTable+='<td> Restaurante: </td>';");
       toClient.println("myTable+='<td>'+"+"myrest[i]"+"+'</td>';");
       toClient.println("myTable+='</tr>';");
    toClient.println("}");
    toClient.println("myTable+='</table>';");
    toClient.println("document.write(myTable);");
    toClient.println("</script>");
    toClient.println("</body>");
    toClient.println("</html>");

}

}
```

The problem is that the javascript array called "myrest" is filled always with the first element of "comentarios" (the java string array). How can i solve this. Thank you

Comment: I am not sure but you seem to be confused here. I maybe wrong though. The Java Applets are small programs that run within a browser, the are still Java programs. They cant render HTML response. The HTML response is supposed to be rendered by a browser. For Java applications to send response back to browser and run, you will need to write a Servlet in Java. Let me know if this makes any sense.

Comment: yes.I have a .class (from .java) called by a browser

Comment: Are you running in it something like tomcat or as an applet in browser? Can you post the complete class file?

Comment: Yes. I'm running it using tomcat. The file is too long... I'm accessing some access databases, let me make it shorter. But, as I said, my problem just that i don't know how to convert a java array into javascript, so I can use it in my .html

Comment: Enter the URL of the servlet in the browser, and the browser will not show anything. Have you tried to view the source in browser. Remember, you are not printing anything that will be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One thing first**: no matter what you are doing, whether you make an applet or a servlet or any other Java application, it is *never* a good idea to make HTML by appending strings. **Never do that!** But as I started my studies and I did the very same (:D) and today I am laughing about it. So let's assume you want to learn Java and you need some hints...

You problem is that the loop in your JavaScript (which you generate) has nothing to do with your Java array. Of course. What you do is that your create another program (a JavaScript program) from your Java code. The two programs (your Java code and the JavaScript it generates) are two completely different applications. So you cannot iterate in JavaScript over a Java array (like you try).

Instead you should iterate in Java over your Java array and generate the JavaScript code. Here's how it could look like (I didn't tested it, it is pseudo-code):

```
toClient.println("var myrest = new Array();"); 
for(String element: myArray)
    toClient.println("myrest.append(" + element + ");");
```

Comment: yes! It works! Just change ".append" with ".push". You're right... I writing the html code by appending strings. Which is the correct alternative?

Comment: Using your solution I'will get a huge html is the array is very long. :(. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @karl71 - yes, the HTML/JavaScript can become very large. But you cannot avoid this. Somewhere you must store the information in your HTML source. The better/correct way to do something like this would be using some kind of template rendering. This is done by a framework (like the Play framework) which would take a template (which is an HTML file with some special syntax) and fill it for you. But the result would also be very large. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTodoList